# What kind of culture and society could humanity develop with one sapient gender?

Tags: society, humans, culture, alternate-worlds, space-constructs

Let's say we launch the first colony ship to a far system. The colony ship engines fail halfway and the ship drifts for a year across the space. The ship was recovered by drones of an automated ringworld built around a star similar to our Sun and is a massive zoo-preserve constructed millions of years ago, but is still in a perfect state. This ringworld is controlled by multiple AIs programmed to preserve alien species, but the main sentient AI is the true master of the ringworld.

The drones secured ten starving human males inside cryopods.

The AI of the ringworld heals and feeds them, but is unable to communicate with the humans for now. Or maybe the AI doesn't want to communicate with the humans. The humans are transported to an island near one big continent of the ringworld with their minds deleted, but in perfect health.

This artificial intelligence, let's call it *Master*, takes some DNA of the survivors and with the advanced alien technology tries to recreate the opposite sex, but it fails for whatever reason.

The master doesn't give up. He experiments for one month and succeeds. With some DNA of one of many xeno fauna living inside the ring it wasn't difficult. Master created a non sentient humanoid females with reptilian traits like eyes and some pink scales at the shoulders, neck and back with bioluminescence, designed only to preserve the human race with wide hips and big breasts to feed offspring etc.

Or at least try... The reptilian traits are inherited, but male offspring has less lizard attributes and they are still sentient. The females are non-sentient, but they are very fertile and can be trained to do mid-complex tasks. And they have a strong maternal instinct.

The xeno lizard girls, created from social and intelligent dinosaur-like pack predators, are very territorial and apprehensive with their partners, but also very loyal and affectionate and hunt land and sea prey with their claws. twenty were created first, but only ten survived the competition. They were designed to have a birth-rate of 50% males, 50% females and they choose the partner that they like to live in a monogamous relationships.

With all that info: **What kind of culture would this society develop.  Let's say 1,000 years have passed and now humans are on the equivalent of early iron age?**

Small Additional question: How would the children be educated?

**Note : Fire was discovered again in the first decades.**

Comment: Did you ever read _[Ethan of Athos](https://www.amazon.com/Ethan-Athos-Lois-McMaster-Bujold/dp/067165604X)_ by Lois Mcmaster Bujold?  Or _[Master of None](https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0446693049/ref=mp_s_a_1_9)_ by N. Lee Wood?

Comment: In 1000 years we went from horses to space flight, from feudalism to democracy, from constant minor wars to constant bigger wars. Who can say what your society would do in such a long time? And it's up to you to decide what Master would allow.

Comment: Having only females makes more sense, lack of Y chromosome could explain problems developing males. Also big breasts don't have anything to do with better feeding. 1) They're like bigger penisses selected for attractiveness, 2) They're filled with fat, fat indicates good reserves. Their nutritional value to infants is the same as small breasts.

Comment: This is **much** too broad. Trying to predict 1 000 years of human development is an impossible task. Just the strides we have made in the past 100 years are completely mind-blowing. I am sorry OP but this is entirely your task. Build your world... we can **assist** you with that. But we will not do that work for you just because you lobbed a scimi... eh... a premise at us.

Comment: @MichaelK the last hundred years are a culmination of millenia of knowledge coming to a head after some key discoveries, it's only been the last 10,000 or so that we stopped being hunter gatherers in some places, the 200,000 years before that we were just nomadic hunter gatherers. The OP's people are starting from the beginning, they're not going to discover spaceflight in 1000 years, they won't even discover how to make petrol, never mind rocket fuel.

Answer (score 7):

Considering that their minds are wiped, they know nothing about technology and that they are in an environment where they don't need technology to survive, they will likely not ever develop technology. In a tropical climate with plenty of wild fruit available all year you don't need agriculture, architecture, energy or textiles to survive winters. Just look at the many indigenous people which still live on a stone-age level of technology even in the present day. It's not like they don't develop because they don't possess the necessary intelligence. This was disproven in the age of colonization when many so-called "primitives" proved to be perfectly capable of using and even creating technology. It's just that they felt no need to do so before they got exposed to European culture.

Your people wouldn't even invent hunting weapons, because the women would do the hunting, and they don't seem to be intelligent enough to use weapons, nor do they need to thanks to their claws and hunting instinct.

That also means there won't be any education. What do you want to teach to your children if you don't know anything about the world outside of the island and have no technology?

If you want this colony of human/reptilian hybrids to develop technologically, you need to give them some reason to struggle. Either make survival gradually harder to force them to adapt by developing technology. Or leave their minds and some of their advanced technology intact, so that they can preserve some of their culture and knowledge and have the hope of escape as a motivation to do so.

Answer (score 4):

With blank minds and any sort of danger in the environment, they'd all die.

If they survived in a thousand years they would be hunter gatherers. The only reason they would be hunters is if they learnt that behaviour from the women. But seeing as no one is going to be cooking the food that might not happen beyond the first generation either. This is assuming their bodies can assimilate alien flora and fauna at all.

Having fire does not automatically mean cooked food, it seems obvious to us, but it's not at all obvious if you don't know food can be cooked to start with. Cooking food is a mission in itself. The NZ Maori prepare their food and wrap it, dig a hole, bury it, then light a fire over it. Other Polynesians burn a big fire full of stones to heat the stones, then put their prepared food in with the hot stones, then cover it with leaves and let it cook.

A likely scenario is one that many islands faced and you say your women are very fertile. In a thousand years they would be at constant war with each other due to population strains and the need to control resources for your immediate family at the expense of others. Large islands like New Zealand had this problem in less than a thousand years with small starting populations. Eventually you can't just keep moving, kinship ties break down, someone steps on someone elses toe or steals their wife, and people start dying all over the place. Tropical islands were even worse, plus they were much smaller.

One of the core reasons for the extreme violence on tropical islands was that people just didn't have much to do to feed themselves. So they had a lot of time to make up reasons to hate their neighbours. And it wasn't uncommon for females to have 15 to twenty children. Population control was practiced by killing your neighbours, not limiting yourselves, because the larger your extended family unit the stronger you were in war.

You would be better off dumping them on a continent with varied habitats and resources and lots of room for expansion, this would give them a much better chance of raising their technological levels dealing with different environments as they expanded and take away the need to have a go at each other in short order. They would still be hunter gatherers after 1000 years, but less likely to be feasting on each other.

Or better yet a tropical island off a continent that is visible on the horizon, they'll find a way to get there when they really need to.